# Cordova Android build fails

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, gradle

I've tried to re install cordova but it hasn't worked
I've checked all System variables
But it haven't worked

I've made the Game with Gdevelop, which means I haven't written the code, it is generated by the game Engine

Code of the Error

What Stacktrace says:

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\MyUsername\BAR\platforms\android\settings.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\MyUsername\BAR\platforms\android\settings.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 62

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62

[...]

*BUILD FAILED in 5s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\MyUsername\BAR\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\MyUsername\BAR\platforms\android\build.gradle*

PS: BAR is the name of the Folder.

When I Run gradlew.bat :cdvBuildDebug --stacktrace I get this:

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\MyUsername\BAR\platforms\android\settings.gradle'
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\MyUsername\BAR\platforms\android\settings.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 62

````
And that is how the Rest looks(I cant paste that all in here)

(at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)
      at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
      at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)
      at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClassNullable(AsmReferenceResolver.java:57)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveClass(AsmReferenceResolver.java:44)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveNonArrayType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:79)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmReferenceResolver.resolveType(AsmReferenceResolver.java:70)...)*```

And that is the End:
      
1 error

      at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
      ... 165 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
````

Comment: That's way to little information to tell why it failed. Please run `gradlew.bat :cdvBuildDebug --stacktrace`.

Comment: 1 error

        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.compileScript(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:139)
        ... 165 more

Comment: Please edit the question; this single one line is just as meaningless as the rest.

Comment: I have now added lot more